# Raspberry pi + cpickle : AttributeError : 'module' object has no attribute 'Tree'

Tags: python-2.7

I trying to estimate the concentration of gas by building the random forest model and pickle the model using cPickle. Here is the code in the file 'regression_rf_dump_model.py'

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
import pandas as pd
import cPickle
import os
#import numpy as np

print "code started"
train = pd.read_csv("D:/FH KOELN/Courses/Semester 3/Prof.Gaida_SVM/TDMR/Test/final_combined_data_random_train.csv") #Reading the file

new_train=train.drop(train.columns[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,118]], axis=1)
colnames=list(new_train)
len_column = len(new_train.columns)
b = len(train)
len_iteration=len_column-1
j=3000
i=0
new_col=pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,b),columns=['temp'])
while i < len_iteration:
    if int(colnames[i])== j:
        i=i+1
        j=j+5;
    else:
        for m in range(0,b):    
            new_col.iloc[m]=(new_train.iloc[m,i-1]+new_train.iloc[m,i+1])/2
        new_train.insert(i,str(j),new_col)
        colnames=list(new_train)
        j=j+5
        i=i+1
        len_iteration=len_iteration+1;


trainRes = train['Methane']    #Response column
trainArr = new_train.as_matrix(colnames) #Convert dataframe into array matrix representation

print "building model"
#For RF 
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=678,max_features=12,min_samples_split=1) 
rf.fit(trainArr, trainRes)  #Fit the random forest model

os.chdir("D:/")
with open('methane_forest1.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(rf, f,-1)
f.close()
```

Using this I was able to generate the pickled model called 'methane_forest1.pickle' file which is around 40mb.

To load the pickled file I created another python file called 'RF_Classification_Pkl_Loading.py' the code is,

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import truediv
import cPickle
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import os
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

with open('/home/pi/2015-06-09_21-19-50_scan_data_22.txt','r') as f:
    data=[x.strip().split('\t') for x in f]
rowno=len(data)
print "No of rows",rowno
colno=len(data[1])
print "No of columns",colno
print data[rowno-1][0]
rn=rowno-1
a=[];
for col in range(2,colno):
    sum =0
    for row in range(rowno-10,rowno):
        sum=sum+float(data[row][col])
    avg=sum/10
    a.append(avg)

with open('/home/pi/BG File.txt','r') as f:
    ref=[x.strip().split('\t') for x in f]
rownof=len(ref)
print "No of rows",rownof
colnof=len(ref[1])
print "No of columns",colnof
b=[];
for col1 in range(2,colnof):
    sum =0
    for row1 in range(rownof-25,rownof):
        sum=sum+float(ref[row1][col1])
    avg1=sum/25
    b.append(avg1)
arr1 = reversed(b)
arr2=[];
meas=[]
meas=map(truediv,a,b)
print len(meas)
meas.pop(140)
meas.pop(139)
meas.pop(138)
meas.pop(137)
print meas

with open('/home/pi/rf_classification_pkl.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    forest2 = cPickle.load(f)
h2s=forest2.predict(meas)

print h2s
timedata=data[rownof-1][0]
date=data[rownof-1][1]
timeinfo=timedata +" "+ date
print timeinfo
Meth=10
Measurement = ET.Element("Measurement")

ET.SubElement(Measurement, "Time").text = timeinfo
ET.SubElement(Measurement, "Methane").text = str(Meth)
ET.SubElement(Measurement, "H2S").text = str(h2s)

tree = ET.ElementTree(Measurement)
os.chdir("/home/pi/")
tree.write("Classification_Result.xml")
```

I copied the pickled file 'methane_forest1.pickle' and 'RF_Classification_Pkl_Loading.py' file to raspberry pi, but I'm getting the error as:

```
AttributeError : 'module' object has no attribute 'Tree'
```

I'm able to execute the same code in my PC but not in raspberry pi. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question. As I explained in the question I was creating the pickle file in my PC which has windows 7 whereas I was trying to load the pickled file in raspberry pi. But my PC and raspberry pi had different versions of sklearn. Because of version conflict I was unable to load the pickled file. After I created the pickled file in raspberry pi, I was able to load it without any errors.